Add server in Pgadmin4 using Terraform
I'm interested in adding servers to Pgadmin4 using Terraform or another suitable tool.
I have successfully deployed a Pgadmin instance using Terraform. Now, I would like to add servers to this instance and organize them into groups during deployment.
My initial thought was to utilize Pgadmin's import/export feature to export servers as a JSON file and then somehow apply this JSON file using Terraform.
Could you please advise on the best approach to achieve this?
I've tried to add it using json file generated but there isn't any pgadmin provider for terraform that would do this.

pgAdmin is a GUI client, it does not actually create servers it just points at them.

i don't want to create servers, but to have them in my pgadmin as i am deploying it. Eg. i deploy my pgadmin instance and i would expect it to have all the connections there.

Then follow the instructions here Import/Export Servers.
